How to handle wrong user input in jetpack compose using regex?
In my Android Jetpack Compose project, I've implemented a regular expression (regex) to validate input. Here's how it looks:
val regex = remember {
    Regex("^(?!0)(?!.*\\.\\..*|\\.$)\\d{0,10}(\\.\\d{0,2})?\$")
}

However, despite this validation, some users are managing to input commas, such as "210,08", and other non-English numerical formats, leading to crashes. How can I address this issue and prevent such input from causing crashes?

Perhaps you could try ^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,9}\\.?[0-9]{0,2})?$ See https://regex101.com/r/FBVQMT/1

You can use String.matches to achieve this.
val regex = remember {
    Regex("^(?!0)(?!.*\\.\\..*|\\.$)\\d{0,10}(\\.\\d{0,2})?\$")
}

val input = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = input.value,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(regex)) {
            input.value = it
        }
    }
)


Yes we are using this still some users are able to enter another language digits. May be they are using another keyboard whatever
